# Google Analytics Tracking Code Causing Slow Down of Iframe-Resizer?

Tags: iframe-resizer

I have an iframe with dynamic content inside that needs to be displayed on a page and I'd like it to show as quickly as possible. However, there seems to be some lag between when the content of the iframe is loaded and when the iframe is resized on the host page. Currently, the initial dimensions of the iframe are height = 0 and width = 100% so that when the content is loaded in the iframe, iframe-resizer will automatically adjust it to the correct height.

However, I noticed that if there is an autoplay video within the iframe, I can hear the audio for as long as a minute before the iframe will get resized. When checking the browser console, I'll see warning messages of iframe-resizer being unresponsive, but after a minute or so, the iframe will get resized and the content will be revealed.

I have a google analytics tracking code within the iframe content and noticed that if I removed it, the iframe-resizer becomes much more responsive and the content gets loaded quicker. How can I get the iframe to act responsive with the google analytics tracking code running inside of it? How can I get the iframe-resizer to work before the GA script finishes loading?

Also, is setting the initial iframe height to 0 and then allowing iframe-resizer to size the frame the proper way to initially load dynamic iframe content?

edit (adding code):
here's the code i run on the host page

```
var hzframe = iFrameResize({
    checkOrigin: false,
    initCallback: function(){
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hzload");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    },
    resizedCallback: function() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hzload");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
},".hzframe");
```

if you want to see the whole thing in action you can check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4d1cb59/)

Currently, I have the same code that hides the loading gif in the initCallback and resizedCallback because the gif doesn't always get hidden by the initCallback.

Comment: You'd have to show us the iframe resizing code. I'd guess you have it set to `onload`, which if GA is loading super-slowly will indeed cause this.

Comment: @ceejayoz I edited my question to include some code. Is there a way to have the iframe resized before the GA script finishes loading or does it have to wait until everything is loaded?

Comment: Is https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer the library you're using?

Comment: yes, it is. It's updated to the most recent version (3.5.14) as well.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm hosting the iframe.resizer.min.js and running the iframeResize function right afterwards in the same file so that the end user who is copy/pasting my code only has one script to run.

Answer (score 0):

If your just hosting a video in your iFrame then this might work better for you.

https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

The issue with GA is very strange, can you defer it running if it is blocking the page load event firing?